# Access multiple servers in a network under a single IP without using ports?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip

I've setup a virtual network at home with 4 PC's.  I want to be able to access these PC's remotely (basically just the http, but rdp and sql would be nice).  I understand I can detect ports and route them, however I have 2 web servers and I want to be able to make everything pretty.

In short, here's what I have:

1. Router with DD-WRT "Large" on it.
2. PhysServer1 - W2K8R2 Physical Server, DNS Server, Domain Controller, Hyper-V Host
3. VirtServer1 - W2K8R2 Virtual Server, SQL Server
4. VirtServer2 - W2K8R2 Virtual Server, Application Build Machine, Web Server for CCNet, Source control, etc...
5. VirtServer3 - W2K8R2 Virtual Server, Application/Web Server, IIS7.5

What I am looking to do is:

1. When I type `http://virtserver2.mydomain.com` my web traffic goes to virtserver2
2. When I type `http://virtserver3.mydomain.com` my web traffic goes to virtserver3
3. When I connect to virtserver1.mydomain.com SSMS connects to virtserver1 for sql services (pretty sure this wont be possible, but tossing it out there)

Is there anything I can do with what's out there (no-ip, dyndns, etc..) or my local DNS/Router to make this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one.. let me just reiterate to see if I got it right.

You have several servers nat behind a DD-WRT router. By necessity they all have the same external IP address, and you want to access them by named service which resolve to the same IP address.

This might be cheating but two mechanism come to mind. The first is setting up a reverse proxy on the DD-WRT node like pound, or the heavier squid that would redirect as appropriate based on name, kind of like a virtual server solution but with different back end servers.

The more complicated mechanism would be to use DD-WRT with l7 iptables support, which would allow you to classify inbound traffic based on virtual destination in the http protocol... stick with pound. :) If it won't do exactly what you want squid can, but it is more complicated..

Here is the link to pound, http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Pound

Comment: You understand what I am trying to do, but I don't quite follow you. Lets leave squid out of it for now and go with your suggested Pound.  I can't find where to download pound, yet alone configure it to run on DD-WRT.  Is there not a way I can setup dyndns to allow the names and have the W2k8 server foward the traffic around?

Comment: In dd-wrt there is some kind of package management. Just ssh in, and use ipkg to install pound. In the pound configuration you want to set up a group for each inbound web domain that forwards to a single backend server, check out http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Simple_webserver_load_balancing_with_pound for a rough idea.

Comment: I can't comment on using W2k8 to forward the traffic, but this is the same solution. I.e using a piece of software as a front end reverse proxy to the connections and then having it do the request. I chose pound only because it is relatively easy to use and is sitting at the logical entry point to your network.